# filter with more than one value on flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want a query with multiple value like `where id in (3,4,5)`

Then I have a `my_list = [3,4,5]` so how can I pass that list as an argument to filter in sqlalchemy?

```
query = Notification.query.filter_by(id=my_list).all()
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use **in_** with **filter**:

```
query = Notification.query.filter(Notification.id.in_(my_list)).all()
```

Here's the relevant [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732222/flask-sqlalchemy-in-method-not-working-for-me), and Read the Doc from [sqlalchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.in_)

Answer (score 2):

In case Notification has a JSON field e.g. data, is there similar syntax to check a list e.g:

```
query = Notification.query.filter(Notification.data['key'].in_(my_list)).all()
```